# java design - which class stores application-wide object?

Tags: java

I have a `Server` object that is obtained when the application runs, and I need to keep it for the duration of the application. It is just a model object with an id, and hostname.

From the standpoint of good software design and separation of concerns, where would the object be stored and how would it be accessed?

Let me provide some code.

```
public interface ServerDao{
    Server findByHost(String host);
}
```

This is how I obtain the object from a DAO. The implementation is irrelevant.

Now let's say I want to have a method called `getCurrentServer` which can be called across the entire application, and it obtains the `Server` object that belongs to the machine that is running the application (based on hostname).

```
public Server getCurrentServer() {
        ServerDao dao = // some way to get it
        try {
            return dao.findByHost(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Host not found", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It's probably a bad idea to place it into the `ServerDao` class. It's probably a bad idea to place it into my `Application` class.

Where would I place such a method? Should I create a `ServerContext` class, with a singleton of the `Server`? What is the standard approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Server has sophisticated and changing state, WHY You say immutable? In term of OO "final object' are immutable ... server sometimes is described as "service"

Comment: i think it makes no difference if it's immutable or not for my question. i removed the irrelevant bit. this question pertains more to application design principles

Comment: Singleton approach seems to be best option.

Comment: @ssc327 Singleton is never the best option.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Use a pattern for its intended purpose, and all is fine. A logger is a good use for a Singleton. Never using a pattern because it can be misused... is just throwing your options away for nothing.

Comment: You can use a singleton for the `Server` but it limits you to only run one server per JVM/Classloader(maybe this is acceptable), a better way would be to to use a dependency injection approach and a context, frameworks like spring provide this for you, but you don’t need a framework to follow the pattern.

Comment: a singleton is acceptable, i need just 1 instance in JVM, but my question is, which class would contain the singleton if im to follow good design patterns?

Comment: Singleton forces you into corners in your code.  Use a single instance, by all means, but don't muck with the construction patterns to try to make the language always return back that single instance.  Doing the latter is where the problems lie.  It is find to have one instance, but really problematic to have the language enforce that only one instance exists.

Comment: @user2914191 Just make the `Server` class itself a singleton? Its hard to say your example code is problematic(it doesnt use DI, where does DefaultDatabaseService get its configuration from?), this question would probably be better suited to the code review stack exchange site, submitted as a complete minimal application.

Comment: @Magnus i dont have DI at the moment but im not sure how its relevant. im trying to refrain from putting any logic into my `Server` model to prevent the model from depending on `ServerDao`.

Comment: The primary reason to use DI is to solve exactly this type of problem.  You have objects that need to be shared and accessed in various places, and the DI framework takes care of making that happen for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a CurrentServer.  The important thing to realize is that CurrentServer is a selection, and that selection is updated by one and shared across the entire application state.

If you want this persisted between runs of the application, you probably need  a CurrentServer DAO, with explicit storage.  Then each of your components can select the CurrentServer and possibly update it.

This means you need a primary key in the database that can only have one value.  Primary Key column `current` with a data type of Boolean, where the value others select is `True` should do the trick.

Now you can have multiple instances of the data, but the instances might grow stale.  This is easier to account for (and more scaleable) than the kind of contention a Singleton approach will eventually cause.

```
public CurrentServer getCurrentServer() {
    CurrentServerDao dao = new CurrentServerDaoImpl(new DefaultDatabaseService());
    try {
        return dao.findByCurrent(Boolean.TRUE);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Host not found", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: let me clarify. i have a `server` table that contains entries for each machine that executes the application. the `server` table has id, and hostname. i simply want the application to obtain an instance of `Server` that belongs to it, based on hostname

Comment: Ok, so it is not a selected server in the sense of selecting a server from all the others.  Just use the DAO's read functionality to "read one's self" from the database.

Comment: but then the function for obtaining the hostname depends on the implementation of the DAO. if i have multiple DAOs then i have multiple copies of the same code. seems like thats not a good way to do it.